# Modal Div to fill entire window including below fold

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an absolute positioned div that I need to get to to fill the entire document for a background to a modal window.

I can get it to fill the window but when there is a scroll bar it doesnt fill the area that is currently visible.

This is my current code:

```
position:absolute;   
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
```

By the way I can get it to fill the document horizontally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give the div `position:fixed` and top,bottom,left,right 0

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sQLPr/

edit - removed the following line

- and it's parent (probably body)
  position:relative

Comment: there is no need to set the position of the body to relative.

Comment: you are right, `position:relative` on the parent is for elements with `position:absolute` to be positioned well. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4):

```
div.covered {position: fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;}
```

test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/kGUYG/2/

Position absolute is gonna scroll when you scroll the page unless you find a JS solution. You need to use position fixed so the element does not scroll when the content does.

Answer (score -3):

Put it in a table with 100% width and that's all

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some code to help answer the question. The OP (original poster) may not know what you mean.

Comment: what is meaning of your answer. put some more effort on answer then it will be understandable.